# When calling function, it returns undefined

Tags: javascript, android

I am making an Android version of CandyBox2 (I know that some already exist but I really want to make a better one).
To save as text, you need to call this function:

```
Save.prototype.clickedFileSave();
```

If I execute it from the Save var it works, I need to call it from the URL.
I tried this:

```
javascript:Save.prototype.clickedFileSave();
```

Or this:

```
javascript:Save.prototype.clickedFileSave.call();
```

Or even this:

```
window[Save.prototype.clickedFileSave]);
```

The last doesn't work at all since it's a function and not a method but the two others return this:

> TypeError: this.getGame(...) is undefined

If you have any idea on how to solve this, I would LOVE to know it.
THANKS !

Here is the Save and Place var (via pastebin, it's big):

- [Save var](http://pastebin.com/6d7KnmRg)
- [Place var](http://pastebin.com/MeU0cbSv)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a fundamental misunderstanding.

The method defined as `Save.prototype.clickedFileSave` is part of the class/object `Save`, and can be called on an instance of `Save`:

```
var game = new Game(...);
var save = new Save(game);
save.clickedFileSave();
```

You cannot call it directly through the prototype unless you pass it an instance of `Save`:

```
Save.prototype.clickedFileSave.apply(save);
```

The error you are getting means that `.getGame(...)` is *also* a method of Save, defined as `Save.prototype.getGame`, and referenced inside `clickedFileSave` with `this.getGame(...)`. In other words, when calling such method, `this` *must* refer to an instance of `Save`.